# Jquery get seventh element in dom

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get 7th element in dom:

```
$('.liabilityBlock'+[7]+' .large-3:last').append(createButtons());
```

But this doesn't work. What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [**:eq()**](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq) selector to select nth element

```
$('.liabilityBlock:eq('+ 6 +') .large-3:last').append(createButtons());
```

As [**@j08691**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691) pointed out correctly, you can use

```
$('.liabilityBlock:eq(6) .large-3:last').append(createButtons());
```

if you always want to select 7th element.

Comment: How about just `:eq(6)`? No need for concatenation.

Comment: Sure it need. But i am instead number past variable. Its simple JS rule.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:eq` selector:

```
$('.liabilityBlock:eq(6) .large-3:last').append(createButtons());
```

**Note:** : Index of eq starts from 0. You should use `.eq(6)` to target seventh element

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `$('.liabilityBlock').eq(6)`.

Answer (score 1):

The seventh element in DOM:

```
$('*').eq(6);
```

if you want to get seventh liability-Block:

```
$('.liabilityBlock').eq(6);
```

If you want to geht last large-3-Element in seventh liability-Block:

```
$('.large-3:last', $('.liabilityBlock').eq(6));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**:eq**](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq) and [**find**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) selectors:

```
$('.liabilityBlock:eq(6)').find('.large-3:last');
```

**PS:** :  `.eq(6)` is used to target seventh element and find is comparitively faster than

```
$('.liabilityBlock:eq(6) .large-3:last');
```

Link: jsperf.com/selector-vs-find-again